# Using Disqus as a Traditional Forum in Wordpress = Powerful Combination

Tags: wordpress, forum, disqus

I haven't found a single good discussion system that combines the power of a forum with the dynamism and convenience of a threaded, on the fly comment system like Disqus/Slashdot/Reddit.

I am wanting to create a discussion system using Disqus in wordpress that works as a traditional forum on the front end, where users can create new categories and subcategories, which are in turn ordered according to the last replies, in descending order. Currently I'm trying and comparing Disqus with bbPress + Threaded comments.

I did find a [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578314/creating-a-website-forum-discussion-group-with-disqus) on stackoverflow, which gave a link to the [API for disqus forums](http://disqus.com/api/docs/forums/).

But I can't seem to find a simple example of a website using it. I really would like to see it in use before I start integrating it into my site! Does anyone know of an example?

Furthermore, will the forum API do what I would like to do, mentioned above? It looks like listThreads might come close, but it's not clear what the difference is between a "post" and a "thread". Also, while there is a *create* option for forums and a *listCategories* option, it is not clear how one would create categories and subcategories in the first place. Again, it would all be clear if I had an example to see.

Answer (score 2):

Channels is a python example of how a mini-forum would be coded if powered by Disqus.

GitHub repo: https://github.com/disqus/channels

Demo: https://pycon.disqus.com/

Comment: Nope, not even close. What I'm seeing there is an active conversations list, and it's not ordered by last reply, and then each conversation is that same non-threaded.
What I need is:

(1) As a traditional forum: Every forum has this, it's what make a forum a forum. A front page, where you see the categories, and the categories have forums or subcategories, and every list of categories/subcategories/forums/topics are listed, descending by the date of last reply.

(2) Like disqus: All conversations are threaded, with full disqus funcionality.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [bbPress](http://bbpress.org/) forum plugin for wordpress with [bbPress Threaded Replies](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bbpress-threaded-replies/) plugin.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm doing that, but would like to see if Disqus could work. It has much more functionality it seems (realtime updating, cleaner look, more connectivity, ongoing updates, etc).